# pandas: groupby column result conditional on another column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

i have a df which looks like this

```
   a  b
0  A  Y
1  A  N
2  A  N
3  B  N
4  B  N
5  B  N
6  B  N
7  C  N
8  C  Y
```

i would like to groupby by column 'a' and column 'b' should show 'Y' whenever at least one entry is 'Y' or 'N' if ALL entries are 'N'

```
   a  b
0  A  Y
1  B  N
2  C  Y
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `max`.

```
df.groupby('a').max().reset_index()

   a  b
0  A  Y
1  B  N
2  C  Y
```

When doing string comparison `'Y'` is greater than `'N'` (i.e. `'Y' > 'N' == True`), so taking the max of column b means it will be 'Y' if there is a single 'Y' in the group, otherwise 'N' will be the max value.

Comment: nice. It would help the OP if you explained that the max works on alphabetical order : ``Y`` > ``N``

Comment: good answer, if the actual dataframe is similar to what mentioned here, this should get the job done +1.

Comment: thanks. what if 'b' would have 'Y', 'N' and 'Z' values where if 'N' or 'Z' it should return 'N' and if any 'Y' it should return 'Y'?

Comment: @idt_tt: you could add a step before it to replace the 'Z' with 'N'. `df['b'] = df['b'].replace('Z', 'N')`